# Is the "else" keyword, used as final case in a cond-expression, a special form in Scheme?

Tags: if-statement, conditional-statements, scheme, special-form

The `cond`-expression in Scheme is a special form, but is the `else` keyword, used as final case in a `cond`-expression, a special form? Or is it just a reserved keyword that is essentially equivalent to the truth-value #t ?
In the latter case, why cannot I write something like `(?eq else #t)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Scheme standards call `else`, as used in a [`cond`](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs/r6rs-Z-H-14.html#node_sec_11.4.5) form, *auxiliary syntax*. [R6RS shows one possible implementation of `cond`](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs/r6rs-Z-H-16.html#node_chap_B) using [`syntax-rules`](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs/r6rs-Z-H-14.html#node_sec_11.19); here `else` is called a *<literal>*:

```
(define-syntax cond
  (syntax-rules (else =>)
    ((cond (else result1 result2 ...))
     (begin result1 result2 ...))
;; ...
```

Note that `else` is not a replacement for `#t`. A *<literal>* is an identifier that is used to match input subforms; it is treated as a syntactic keyword within the `syntax-rules` form.

Answer (score 3):

It's part of the syntax of `cond` and `case`. [R<sup>7</sup>RS](https://small.r7rs.org/attachment/r7rs.pdf) specifies the following syntax:

```
(cond <cond clause>+)
(cond <cond clause>* (else <tail sequence>))

(case <expression>
  <case clause>+)
(case <expression>
  <case clause>*
  (else <tail sequence>))
```

It's not defined outside the syntax of these special forms.

Answer (score 1):

Neither. You can test this by evaluating `else` outside of a `cond`: it behaves just like any other unbound symbol. The `cond` macro treats it specially, but there is nothing inherently special about it in any other context.

Comment: It doesn't behave as an unbound symbol. When using an unbound symbol I would get something like ``cannot reference undefined identifier else'' but instead when using else in another context than the last cond case I get this error instead: ```else not allowed as an expression```. So I guess it is syntactically imposed to be only used in the context of an else, even though semantically it can be seen as a #t true value.

Comment: @KimMens I don't think that's required by the language specification, it sounds like an extra sanity check by your implementation.